# bindAttr calls error 'TypeError: elem is undefined' when collection of views rerendered

Tags: ember.js

I'm using an `Ember.CollectionView` with an `itemView` that contains `{{bindAttr class="App.offersController.filters.profile:selected"}}`.

When `App.offersController.filters` changes, the collectionView rerender each itemView.

When I use `{{bindAttr class="App.offersController.filters.profile:selected"}}`, I receive error `TypeError: elem is undefined` on line 18675, Ember try to change attribute that was destroyed with old view.

In Ember's code i see comments:

> If we can't find the element anymore, a parent template has been re-rendered and we've been nuked. Remove the observer.

It works when i use `{{App.offersController.filters.profile}}`, but not with `{{bindAttr class="App.offersController.filters.profile:selected"}}`

Comment: could you add a JSFiddle, the Ember file you're using ?

Comment: As @Matt. answer, try to update your version, if it does not work, perhaps this is related to https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1279. In this case, it seems to have a workaround by using `{{with}}` or `{{unless}}` helpers enclosing the `{{bindAttr}}`

Comment: I did http://jsfiddle.net/2dqrk/1/, but it's work :(. But my code doesn't work. I understand why, in ember-1.0.pre.js in line 18671 view.$() returns undefined, but should returns []

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your ember.js into latest because there is an issue in ember.10.pre. Please refer [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1307)

Comment: I don't know if it's related to this issue, but +1 as it can be usefull to check that.